# Is there a way to stop bash from parsing zsh code?

Tags: bash

I have a file which is sourced from `.bashrc` and `.zshrc` which contains some functions. It was previously two separate files (for each shell), but I am now using a single file as the files were nearly identical and it's easier for me to manage a single functions file.

There is a function which is different for the two shells, so I thought I could use a conditional statement so that the correct one is used:

```
[[ $BASH_VERSION ]] && shell=bash
[[ $ZSH_VERSION ]] && shell=zsh

# Search man page for string
if [[ $shell == bash ]]; then
  mans() {
    local q="\'"
    local q_pattern="'${1//$q/$q\\$q$q}'"
    local MANPAGER="less -+MFX -p $q_pattern"
    man "$2"
  }
elif [[ $shell == zsh ]]; then
  mans() MANPAGER="less -+MFX -p ${(q+)1}" man $2
fi
```

This seems to work fine in zsh, but when switching to bash I get an error from the zsh line, even though it's not supposed to be used in bash. Is there any way to stop it from parsing that line?

Comment: Are you switching to zsh by calling bash from zsh, or are you starting from scratch (for example by calling chsh -s /bin/bash and logging out and in again)?

Comment: @Wieland  I was just switching by typing bash from within zsh to test it, but I also get the error after changing the default shell to bash using `chsh` and logging out and back in again.

Comment: Why not refactor so that the different part continues to exist in separate files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Others already pointed out why bash is parsing syntactically the contents of the `$shell == zsh` conditional.

On zsh you can use

```bash
  mans() MANPAGER="less -+MFX -p ${(q+)1}" man $2
```

whereas that's not legal bash syntax (a function would need {}).

However, on zsh you can also use POSIX syntax for functions, which will keep both shells happy:

```bash
elif [[ $shell == zsh ]]; then
  mans() {
    MANPAGER="less -+MFX -p ${(q+)1}" man $2
  }
fi
```

Additionally, I would generally change those `[[` to single `[` syntax so the file won't break if run on other shells (such as `dash`) not supporting `[[`:

```bash
[ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ] && shell=bash
[ -n "$ZSH_VERSION" ] && shell=zsh

# Search man page for string
if [ "$shell" = bash ]; then
  mans() {
    local q="\'"
    local q_pattern="'${1//$q/$q\\$q$q}'"
    local MANPAGER="less -+MFX -p $q_pattern"
    man "$2"
  }
elif [ "$shell" = zsh ]; then
  mans() {
    MANPAGER="less -+MFX -p ${(q+)1}" man $2
  }
fi
```

Comment: While there are other answers which give useful methods for future problems that I may have, this is a very simple solution for this particular function.

Comment: ..but I don't think making the tests POSIX compliant is required when this file is being sourced from .bashrc and .zshrc and will in currently only be souced by bash or zsh.

Comment: @paradroid: making other shells not choke on the file was just a bonus. As you have previously ensured it will be only loaded by bsh or zsh, it's not really needed.

Comment: Note that a function body in bash (or in POSIX standard sh syntax) doesn't need `{}` specifically, it  needs a *compound* command, `{ ...; }` being one of them. While in the Bourne shell and most other Bourne-like shells including zsh, that can be any command.

Comment: @paradroid Note that `${(q+)var}` is also invalid syntax in bash. It doesn't complain here because current versions of bash are doing lazy parsing, but you might find that future versions of bash will choke on it.

Answer (score 12):

You could define some `ifbash`, `ifzsh`, `endif` aliases such as:

```
alias if{ba,z}sh=':||:<<"endif"' endif=
if [[ -n $BASH_VERSION ]]; then
  alias ifbash=
  shopt -s expand_aliases
elif [[ -n $ZSH_VERSION ]]; then
  alias ifzsh=
fi

ifbash
f() { echo bash; }
endif

ifzsh
f() echo ${(q+):-zsh}
endif
```

`:||:<<"MARKER"` ... `MARKER` is an idiomatic way to comment out a section of code. That's like `:<<"MARKER"` to run the `:` noop builtin with a here-doc on stdin, but with the extra `:||`, the second `:` is not run and the here-document not even created, just parsed away.

Beware that the `endif` must not be indented out nor followed by anything; it must make up the whole line. `ifbash`/`ifzsh`s cannot be nested (not that it would make sense anyway here).

BTW, `man` seems to be doing the quote parsing in the `MANPAGER` environment variable by itself (as opposed to invoking a shell, let alone your `$SHELL`) and doesn't seem to support the `$'...'` form of quotes, so using the `q+` parameter expansion flag which may use that form of quotes for some strings is not correct. Use `qq` instead which uses single quotes (and `\'` outside of quotes to escape the single quotes¹) like in your bash version.

---

<sup>¹ unless the `rcquotes` option is enabled in which case `''` à la `rc` is used instead. Adding `emulate -L zsh` at the start of your function, to have a sane local set of options in that function wouldn't help as the option needs to be disabled at the time the function is defined, not run.</sup>

Answer (score 9):

Bash still has to *parse* the whole file, even if it's not going to execute every line. You usually can't hide *syntax* errors behind a conditional, only runtime errors.

In your place, I would go back to using separate `.zshrc` and `.bashrc`. I would then put the common functions in a *third* file (ensuring that this file only used syntax compatible with both) and source it from both `.zshrc` and `.bashrc`.

To my mind, this is the best of all worlds:

1. The zsh-only functions would go in `.zshrc` where they would never be read by bash. Likewise bash-only stuff lives in `.bashrc`.
2. The common functions would have a single definition, so you don't have to maintain two copies (and they would be in a file that is explicitly cross-shell, so you're less likely to forget about keeping it compatible with both).
3. Each shell would have its startup file with the standard name so it's more clear and obvious where they are configured, and each would explicitly declare that they also use the common file.
4. No need to maintain shell syntax inside shell strings (which gets painful when the quoting is any more complex than in your example, loses syntax highlighting, etc etc).

Comment: Thanks, but I am actually essentially already doing this. The functions file is the third file which is shared by both and there is only this function which has the conditional and the solution has turned out to be a very simple. I agree that this could be a way to do it otherwise though.

Answer (score 6):

Any shell has to parse the code inside the conditional to find the part where the conditional ends, even if for no other reason.

In addition to putting the shell-specific code in another file or in a string to `eval`, you might be able to also use a here-doc to hide it and `source` the here-doc directly. Pretty much the same as using `eval`, but a here-doc has the advantage that the code inside can contain both single and double-quotes without any annoying escaping issues.

E.g. this script says `hello, 'bar', I'm zsh` if run with zsh, and throws an error in Bash:

```
if [[ -n $ZSH_VERSION ]]; then
    source /dev/stdin <<'EOF'
foo() {
   echo "hello, '$1', I'm zsh"
}
EOF
fi

foo bar
```

I'm not sure if `source /dev/stdin` works with all shells and systems, though. (And yes, `source` is a nonstandard name for the `.` builtin, but it should work in Bash and zsh, and anyway the command only needs to exist in the shell that runs the inside of the conditional.)

Comment: This doesn’t work in Cygwin.  (Disclosure: I’m running a fairly old version.)  Cygwin is notorious for mis-handling corner cases like this. … … … … `source /dev/stdin` works — but it reads everything up to an end of file.  You can use Ctrl+D in the terminal, but, in a file, it would have to be the actual end of the file.  OTOH, *`some-command `* `/dev/stdin << EOF`, in general, fails.  The shell reads the here-document up to the `EOF`  string, as usual, but then *`some-command`* gets an error when it tries to open `/dev/stdin`.  (This is equally true for `source` and for non-builtin programs.)

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica', yeah, I've the impression that e.g. different kinds of fds aren't as interchangeable in Windows as on Unixen, so `/dev/stdin` not working probably shouldn't be surprising. Oh well, too bad.

Answer (score 4):

The method [suggested by @ilkkachu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/744915/is-there-a-way-to-stop-bash-from-parsing-zsh-code?noredirect=1#comment1416502_744915) worked:

```
# Search man page for string
if [[ $shell == bash ]]; then
  mans() {
    local q="\'"
    local q_pattern="'${1//$q/$q\\$q$q}'"
    local MANPAGER="less -+MFX -p $q_pattern"
    man "$2"
  }
elif [[ $shell == zsh ]]; then
  mansfunc='mans() MANPAGER="less -+MFX -p ${(q+)1}" man $2'
  eval "$mansfunc"
fi
```